# How to get Ajax responce in Framework7?

Tags: ajax, phonegap-build, html-framework-7

I am new to Framework7. In this code i am not getting response from Ajax.
Guide me please.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Path to your app js --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>

    var myApp = new Framework7();  
    var $$ = Dom7;

    $$('.form-to-json').on('click', function(){
        var name = $$('#name').val();
        var password = $$('#password').val();
        var data = {"name":name,"password":password};
         $$.ajax({
            url: "validation.php",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert("data");
            }
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

Validation Page

```
<?php
echo "Hi";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight error in your code. In the callback, you are displaying alert("data") which will always display "data". To display what's been sent from the php script, you need to change alert("data") to alert(data).